# I don't care what they say

Tags: syntactic-analysis, direct-objects, verb-phrases

> 1. I don't care about what they say.

In the sentence above, they phrase *what they say*, is presumably the complement of the preposition *about*, and the preposition phrase *about what they say* is presumably the complement of the verb *care*.

I am interested in the following sentence

> 2. I don't care what they say.

My question here is: Is *what they say* the direct object of the verb *care*. If so, why and if not, why not? What evidence do we have either way.

Comment: To me, example 1 means "I don't care about what they say I care about."

Comment: @GregLee Yes, I can get that reading out of that too (as well as the (2)-style reading).

Comment: @GregLee This is a preparatory question regarding an analysis of "I don't give a crap what they say" and whether "a crap what they say" is a constituent there, or whether *give* is taking two complements. Any ideas?

Comment: @GregLee... yes, that's one way to understand it, but surely not the only/most obvious way? To me, both sentences are equivalent to "Their stated opinion is irrelevant to me", unless contextual information says otherwise.

Comment: My suggestion: "I don't [V give a crap] [PP (about) what they say]."

Comment: To be Od "what they say" would have to be an NP in a fused relative construction, but it would make no sense to say "I don't care that which they say". If the prep "about" is added, I suppose it is arguable whether it is a subordinate interrogative (embedded question) or a fused relative: "I don't care (about) the answer to the question 'What do they say?"' vs "I don't care about that which they say". The prep "about" is certainly optional in the interrogative reading, which would be my preference.

Comment: @GregLee Is the *what they say* there a complement of *give a crap*?

Comment: I don't know. --

Comment: 'I don't care what they say' really means 'whatever they say'. It is undefined, for it is not quantifiable. It refers to all that anyone might say.
If the person was being definite, it would be 'I don't care what they said.' They would be referring to a particular statement, once made.

Comment: I don't think it means that I don't care about the specific thing that they are saying, but that I don't care about whatever they may say, i.e. they can say what(ever) they like and I wouldn't care about it. In this reading "what they say" is thus an interrogative as **complement** of "care" (or of "about" in your first example, where it is licensed by "care about"). In your "crap" example "what they say" is complement of "crap".

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/care) should give us an indication, with two different definitions:

> **care** (intransitive): to feel interest or concern . *care* about freedom
>
> **care** (transitive): to be concerned about or to the extent of . don't *care* what they say. doesn't *care* a damn

In summary, the transitive sense:

1. Is more restrictive, since "interest" is not part of it. In fact, as the examples show it is used chiefly in the negative, i.e. to deny that one is *concerned*. Furthermore, there is a limit on the construction: one could say "I don't care what they say", but one wouldn't say "I don't care my friends".
2. May imply a degree: *I don't care (a bit, the least, a damn, a hoot, etc.)*

(In the second case, however, I would rather consider "the least" as an adverbial phrase, as it would be in e.g. French, but that might be question onto itself.)

As matter of fact, I have the suspicion that this particular phrase "I don't care *what*" is an [ellipsis](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/ellipsis) of "I don't care **about** what", but I don't have enough elements to support that assertion, except that it belongs to a more casual register.

Comment: Sadly, dictionaries often become quite sloppy when they need to venture into areas of grammar. They either make gross oversimplifications or adopt one analysis out of many available, and are slow to change when more modern scholarship is seen to have better explanations (some still don't accept the determiner/determinative class).